# Make a dot plot in Python using a data file that consists of list of arrays

Tags: python, plot, histogram, dataformat

I have two arrays (of equal length) that define the length of x- and y-axis.

for e.g:

```
x_array = np.arange(xmin, xmax, xbins)
y_array = np.arange(ymin, ymax, ybins)
```

With this I can plot an xy-grid. On every bin (x_{i} - x_{i-1},y_{i} - y_{i-1}) of this grid I want a dot plot of the frequency of occurrence of some quantity z. I already know the frequency of occurrence of z but it is in this format:
 (array([9460,    3,  172,   76,   79,  121,  201,    0,  115,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0]) array([9460,    3,  172,   76,   79,  121,  201,    0,  115,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0]))

To plot this frequency on top of the grid I need to do something like this:

```
for x in x_array:
    for y in y_array:
       plot(x,y,data[x][y])
```

but I can read the data only as lines not as arrays. How do I get around this?

Comment: What do you mean with 'read data only as lines'? What are you trying to do with that last plot? i,v where are they defined? Are you trying to show a 3D plot?

Comment: Hi! Sorry, I meant x and y. Yes I would like to get a 3d plot or a 2d-density plot like this (https://oceanpython.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/2d_histogram3.png). I meant that I am not able to access the frequency value corresponding to [x][y]. I tried the following:with open("test_hist.txt", "r") as ins:
    array = []
    for line in ins:
        array.append(line)

print array[0] and this can read every line of data but not every array.

Answer (score 1):

1. The snippet above - `(array([455127, 36160,` etc - is this the actual text content of the file? You might be able to load the data like

   ```
   import ast

   with open('test_hist.txt') as inf:
       # grab the file contents as string
       text = inf.read()
       # make it look like Python instead of PHP
       text = "[" + text.replace('(', '').replace('array', '').replace(')', '') + "]"
       # parse string to data structure
       data = ast.literal_eval(text)
   ```
2. **Edit:** ok, the data is pre-binned; after a quick look at the [matplotlib gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) I found a [close match to your desired output](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/hist2d_log_demo.html) using the [pyplot.hist2d() function](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=hist2d#matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d). We can modify it to use your data like so:

   ```
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
   from numpy import arange

   height, width = len(data), len(data[0])
   xs, ys, weights = [], [], []
   for yval, row in zip(arange(0., 30., 0.3), data):
       for xval, weight in zip(range(0, 10000, 100), row):
           xs.append(xval)
           ys.append(yval)
           weights.append(weight)

   plt.hist2d(xs, ys, bins=[width, height], weights=weights, norm=LogNorm())
   plt.colorbar()
   plt.show()
   ```

   which (on the given sample data) produces
   [image]
   **Edit 2:** fixed axis ranges!

Comment: Hi yes, its already the binned values. Its a a file of arrays where each array gives frequency of occurrences of a range of xvalues and a fixed yvalue.